# How can the result of this LINQ query be of type IQueryable<> and not of type IEnumerable<>?

Tags: linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects, iqueryable

I understand that next query throws an exception since `IQueryable<>` provider doesn't support `Enumerable.TakeWhile` extension method.

```
        IQueryable<Contact> search = context.Contacts.TakeWhile(q => q.ContactID > 10);
        foreach(var q in search); // exception
```

But it gets confusing if I try to understand the preceding query from C#'s point of view.

Since last Linq method to be called in above chain is *Linq-to-Objects* `TakeWhile`, I'd expect `search` variable to be of type `IEnumerable<T>` , but instead it is of type IQueryable (I know that `IQueryable<T>` queries are converted into *expression trees*, while *Linq-to-Objects* queries are essentially converted into deferred method calls, so trying to convert an *expression tree* (created by `context.Contacts` ) into  method calls wouldn't work. As said, this is confusing to me from C#'s point of view ).

Also, the way `Queryable` operators build up their queries is by calling on `IQueryProvider<T>.CreateQuery`, which given an *expression tree* build up new `IQueryable<T>` objects. Doesn't this mean that somehow `IEnumerable<T>.TakeWhile` operator must know to either build an *expression tree* by itself (which it doesn't) or must be able to call `IQueryProvider<T>.CreateQuery`?

I'm pretty sure my assumptions are wrong, so can someone explain how is the preceding query able to return a result of type `IQueryable<T>` instead of `IEnumerable<T>`?

thank you in advance

Comment: @Johan Larsson: thank you for noticing - I corrected the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IQueryable<T>.TakeWhile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535033.aspx) returns IQueryable<T>

[IEnumerable<T>.TakeWhile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535033.aspx) returns IEnumerable<T>

```
[Test]
public void TakeWhileTest()
{
    List<int> ints = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4};
    var enumerable = ints.AsEnumerable().TakeWhile(x => x < 3);
    Assert.IsNotInstanceOf<IQueryable<int>>(enumerable);
    foreach (var i in enumerable)
    {

    }
    IQueryable<int> queryable = ints.AsQueryable().TakeWhile(x => x < 3);
    Assert.IsInstanceOf<IQueryable<int>>(queryable);
    foreach (var i in queryable)
    {

    }
}
```

The above works, my guess is that you try to get q.ContactId from a q that is null.
You can try this (and skip the TakeWhile):

```
foreach (var contact in context.Contacts)
{
    if (contact.ContactID > 10)
        break;
    //Do your stuff here
}
```

Comment: 1) Interesting, it is indeed of that type, but why do I then get 'NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method ...'? Shouldn't/don't Linq-to-Entities providers support all Queryable methods? 2) Was I correct that if last operator in chain was Linq-to-Objects operator (which it isn't in this example), then result should in that case always be IEnumerable<T> and not IQueryable<T>?

Comment: Updated answer, what exception do you get?

Comment: I had to comment out Assert.IsInstanceOf, since I don't have NUnit, but other than that your code works. I get "System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[ConsoleApplication1.Contact] TakeWhile[Contact(System.Linq.IQueryable`1[ConsoleApplication1.Contact], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[ConsoleApplication1.Contact,System.Boolean"

Comment: Yes - I don't think that the problem is with the Contact entity, since I am able to perform many "normal" Linq-to-Entities queries on a Contact EntitySet - ups you deleted a comment to which I was responding to

Comment: Can I just also ask if I was correct that if last operator in chain was Linq-to-Objects operator (which it isn't in this example), then result should in that case always be IEnumerable<T> and not IQueryable<T>?

Comment: That seems to be correct [according to the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397919.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Queryable.TakeWhile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549146%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) as well as an [Enumerable.TakeWhile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534804%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: 1) Interesting, it is indeed of that type, but why do I then get 'NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method ...'? Shouldn't/don't Linq-to-Entities providers support all Queryable methods? 2) Was I correct that if last operator in chain was Linq-to-Objects operator (which it isn't in this example), then result should in that case always be IEnumerable<T> and not IQueryable<T>?

Comment: @carewithl - This article shows which Queryable methods linq-to-entities supports http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550.aspx

Comment: thanx for the link - though I find it confusing why Linq-to-Entities is not able to support all Queryable methods